# How to make dropify for multiple attachment

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropify

I am using the Dropify jQuery plugin for attachment but I am unable to add multiple attachments at the same time. I am using it in ASP.Net MVC5. Here is my code

```
<input type="file" id="MemberImage" name="MemberImage" class="dropify" data-default-file="@Model.MemberImage" data-height="230" />
```

```js
$('.dropify').dropify();
```

Comment: Dropify does not support multiple file inputs. If you need this you will have to create repeated single file inputs, or use a better library.

Comment: I'm not sure the plugin supports multiple attachments

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you suggest me some other plugin to upload multiple attachment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write **multiple** in Your Tag

```
<input type="file" id="MemberImage" name="MemberImage" class="dropify" data-default-file="@Model.MemberImage" data-height="220" multiple/>
```

Notes:
Dropify displays only one image of the selected